# How would a ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected be vulnerable to SQL Injection?

Tags: sql, oracle, code-injection

Suppose I have a web application. I do not know the backend. I submit some forms, and finally, end up at a error message.

It states:

> ORA--0923: FROM keyword not found where expected.

So, we know that this means that the developer programmed something similar to this:

```
SELECT *

employees;
```

which is missing a from keyword, or it's not where it's expected.

So now that you have the query

```
SELECT * employees;
```

Theoretically how would you inject this?

Comment: "we know that this means ... something similar to this" - no we don't, really. There are other ways to malform SQL to generate this error. If there is a backend query that usually works but you can manipulate the inputs to cause that error then it does seem to be vulnerable, but that's down to how that backend query is being constructed. What you've shown doesn't really help - that (invalid) query is not itself vulnerable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say the database is trying to execute a simple statement like

```
select 'smith' from dual;
```

The developer has, instead of using a bind variable, concatenated the string 'smith' (with quotes) into a statement

A hacker then tries a name with a single quote in it

```
select 'o'reilly' from dual;
```

That breaks the app with the error

```
ORA-01756: quoted string not properly terminated
```

They then try the string `' where 1=1'` which gets converted to the statement

```
select '' where 1=1'' from dual;
```

which errors with

```
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
```

There are other keywords (eg ORDER BY) that would give the same error, so it is possible you've stumbled across one.

Generally that should be sufficient for a bug report.

Comment: But could you do a SQL injection on a website with an error like this?

Answer (score 2):

For sql injection to be possible, the query would have to have parameters or bind variables being passed to it from the web interface. This query is syntactically incorrect without any parameters. The only way that this query could be involved in a sql injection scenario would be if the web application accepted the entire query and then executed it.

Comment: If I do not play with the forms inserting junk data there is no error.